# BeautifulSoup scraping is returning {{ variable }} rather than the text shown on the page

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data from a website, using BeautifulSoup, and the text I'm getting back what appears to be Django tags e.g. {{ ResultLink }} rather than the actual URL that I can see when I view page source.

How would I go about retrieving the text shown on the page instead? Is it possible within BeautifulSoup?

My code is this:

```
    req = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

    if bsObj.find("div", {"id" : {"exactresult"}}) is not None:
        price = bsObj.find_all("div", {"class" : {"price-details"}})[0].get_text()
        link = bsObj.find_all("a", {"class" : {"btn-plate"}})[0].get_text()
```

Both `price` and `link` are returning variables within {{ }} rather than the text that is showing on the webpage.

I have used near identical code on many other websites (with relevant class names etc) and works fine there, so appears something specific with the website I'm looking at.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide the url?

Comment: Hi there, it is `url = https://www.regplates.com/search?search={0}'.format(reg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is populated using Javascript. You can get the data by making a POST request to their API with the search term. This will return a `json` response which contains all the data including the top one.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#change 'ash1' to your search term
payload={"search":"ash1"}
req = requests.post('https://www.regplates.com/api/search',json=payload)
price=req.json()['data']['exact']['price']
link=req.json()['data']['exact']['link']
print(price,link,sep="\n")
```

Output

```
688800
/number-plate/ASH-1
```

The json response may be very large depending on the search term. A simple way to make sense of it would be to use `pprint`

```
import pprint
...
pprint.pprint(req.json())
```

Alternatively you could also use [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to get the data.